# JavaScript setInterval for animation

Tags: javascript, animation, setinterval

So far I have this code for moving an element along the page: http://jsfiddle.net/rwowf5j8/

```
<body onload="anim(document.getElementById('test'), 'left', 'px', 140, 300, 500);">
 <p id='test'>LOL</p>

<script>
    function anim(elem,style,unit,from,to,time) {
    if( !elem) return;
    var start = new Date().getTime(),
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            var step = Math.min(1,(new Date().getTime()-start)/time);
            elem.style[style] = (from+step*(to-from))+unit;
            if( step == 1) clearInterval(timer);
        },25);
    elem.style[style] = from+unit;
}


    </script>
</body>
```

It works great, but how do I add a setInterval method to this code to make the function "anim" repeat regularly to create repeated movement?

I have tried changing the  tag with the call of the function to this:

```
<body onload="setInterval(anim(document.getElementById('test'), 'left', 'px', 140, 300, 500), 500);">
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the code in an anonymous function like this:

```
<body onload="setInterval(function(){anim(document.getElementById('test'), 'left', 'px', 140, 300, 500)}, 500)">
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setInterval()` function expects a function and a delay. Your `anim` function doesn't return anything so it doesn't work.

You need something like this:

```
setInterval(function(){anim(document.getElementById('test'), 'left', 'px', 140, 300, 500)}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set it up inside the function so that it calls itself after the interval.

```
   function anim(elem,style,unit,from,to,time) {
        if( !elem) return;

        var start = new Date().getTime(),
            timer = setInterval(function() {
                var step = Math.min(1,(new Date().getTime()-start)/time);
                elem.style[style] = (from+step*(to-from))+unit;
                if( step == 1) clearInterval(timer);
            },25);
        elem.style[style] = from+unit;

        setInterval(function(){
            anim(elem,style,unit,from,to,time);
        }, time);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to wrap `anim` function in another `setInterval`, you can make cycle animation by changing

```
if( step == 1) clearInterval(timer);
```

to

```
if( step == 1) start = new Date().getTime();
```

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwowf5j8/2/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the content of the first parameter needs to go between quotes or wrapped in a function.

If you change what you have:

```
<body onload="setInterval(anim(document.getElementById('test'), 'left', 'px', 140, 300, 500), 500);">
```

and wrap the "anim" call in single quotes:

```
<body onload="setInterval('anim(document.getElementById(\'test\'), \'left\', \'px\', 140, 300, 500)', 500);">
```

It looks ugly, but it works just fine. You can see it in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rwowf5j8/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to leverage closures or `Function.bind` here. In your `setInterval` example, you are directly calling `anim` before passing the return value of `anim` into the call to `setInterval`.  What you meant to do is pass the function itself in to setInterval.  You can use `Function.bind` to pass the parameters you want.

Try using `<body onload="setInterval(anim.bind(undefined, document.getElementById('test'), 'left', 'px', 140, 300, 500));">`

The full example is below.

```js
function anim(elem,style,unit,from,to,time) {
    if( !elem) return;
    var start = new Date().getTime(),
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            var step = Math.min(1,(new Date().getTime()-start)/time);
            elem.style[style] = (from+step*(to-from))+unit;
            if( step == 1) clearInterval(timer);
        },25);
    elem.style[style] = from+unit;
}
```

```css
#test {
position: absolute;
left: 140px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="setInterval(anim.bind(undefined, document.getElementById('test'), 'left', 'px', 140, 300, 500));">
 <p id='test'>LOL</p>
```